# Debug error! The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call

Tags: c

When I attempt to run the following function,I got the following the error.Otherwise,When completing the process of function,I'm receiving the error.

```
 Debug error!

 The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. 
 This is usually a    result of calling a function declered with one calling 
 convention with a fonction pğointer declered with a different calling convention.
```

Code:

```
 typedef int(*FPROC)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,int,int);
 HINSTANCE hDllInstance;
 FPROC pmyfonk;
 hDllInstance = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mydll.dll"));
 if (hDllInstance==NULL) {MessageBox("...dll yok............");
 exit(0);
 }

 pmyfonk=(FPROC)GetProcAddress(hDllInstance,TEXT("myfonk"));
 pmyfonk(TEXT("xxx"),TEXT("xxy"),TEXT("xxz"),NULL,TEXT("xy"),1,1);//this function is working.But,I'm getting upper error.

 FreeLibrary(hDllInstance);
```

Comment: Could you show the function declaration from the DLL?

Comment: @user980020 There is actually no unicode version of `GetProcAddress`, so you should not use the `TEXT()` macro for its second parameter. Also, because the function type `FPROC` only accepts `char*`, you also shouldn't use the macro when calling `pmyfonk` or else the build will fail when `UNICODE` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx

There is a mismatch between calling convention somewhere in your code. I'm new to windows programming so I don't know much more but this is clearly what the error message tells.

Comment: The signature of myfonk is not FPROC, he's probably missing `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`, not sure which.

Answer (score 3):

By default, there's __cdecl calling convention used. I suppose that your DLL function uses __stdcall convention. The difference is that stack must be cleaned by caller with __cdecl and by callee with __stdcall. I think you mess up with something like that. [Here you can find](http://www.hackcraft.net/cpp/MSCallingConventions/) good explanation of these conventions.